# I'm getting Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, I've tried to write some code, but I'm getting a rendering issue and I don't know why. Everything seems fine, but I don't know why I'm getting errors. Here is my code:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  const names = [
    {id:1, prenom:"Hugu"},
    {id:2, prenom:"The"},
    {id:3, prenom:"Marie"},
    {id:4, prenom:"Den"},
    {id:5, prenom:"Er"},
    {id:6, prenom:"Jac"},
    {id:7, prenom:"Chris"},
    {id:8, prenom:"Sa"}
  ];

  let lst=names.map((valeur)=><List id={valeur.id} prenom={valeur.prenom}>);
  console.log(lst);
  const Family=React.createClass({
    render:function(){
      return(
        <div>
          {lst}
        </div>
      )
    }
  });

  //Formatage de l'affichage des enfants
  const List=React.createClass({
    render:function(){
      return (
        <div>
          <p>ID : {this.props.id} <br />
          Prenom : {this.props.prenom}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
  });

  ReactDOM.render(<div><Family /></div>, document.getElementById('container'))
</script>
```

After execution I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token
```

in the browser and nothing is displaying, and the errors seems to come from the `render` function.

Comment: You need to close your JSX tag. `let lst=names.map((valeur)=><List id={valeur.id} prenom={valeur.prenom} />);`

Comment: I've closed my JSX tag,the erros has changed to `react.min.js:16 Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings` and not alway rendering

Comment: Have you tried using the non-minified environment to get a better error message?

Comment: I'm new to react,when you talk about non-minified environment what do you min?to user `react.js` file instead of `react.min.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving your `<List>` definition above where you have:

```
let lst = names.map((valeur)=><List id={valeur.id} prenom={valeur.prenom} />);
```

Comment: Thank you,it works.I forgot that the code is executed from top to bottom,so i used List component before creating it